# Could someone walk me through this paragraph on the works of Sarah Lucas?

Tags: deconstruction, feminism

1. Is the following paragraph talking about a specific artwork by Sarah Lucas titled ["Self- Portrait with Fried Eggs"](http://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/lucas-self-portrait-with-fried-eggs-p78447) or her series of photographs called "Self- Portrait"?
2. What is the "eternal triangle" here?
3. what does "One suspects that the ancient Indian model would have got the joke." mean?

Context:

> ...Though such thinking has contributed to a commonplace feminist deconstruction, it doesn’t mean that women themselves are not complicit with this state of affairs – witness the vacuous obsession with beauty in women’s magazines. Our ambivalence is reflected in Sarah Lucas’ work, the statement of a modern self-determined young woman, who artfully displays the eternal triangle in an attitude that is an ironic combination of crude defiance and flirtatious come-on. One suspects that the ancient Indian model would have got the joke.

Quoted from in [Art and Science](https://books.google.de/books?id=xCkBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA82&lpg=PA82&dq="Though+such+thinking+has+contributed+to+a+commonplace+feminist"&source=bl&ots=E_d3LqGb0C&sig=ZYfFaf3VQhkG4riUXO8jLnzGaD8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Though%20such%20thinking%20has%20contributed%20to%20a%20commonplace%20feminist%22&f=false) by Sian Ede

Comment: Welcome to Phil.SE! it's generally seen as being useful (and good practise) to say where quotes have been sourced, and just as importantly who by; and if it is online to link to it - this generally attracts better quality answers from this community.

Comment: Also, I find it quite hard to see where 'philosophy-of-mind' is involved in either the question, or the extract - it appears more aligned with feminist philosophy; and this too, given the use of the term 'deconstruction' in the article - ie deconstructing gender and sexual roles; so possibly 'deconstruction' and 'feminist-philosophy' are the more appropriate tags to go for.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the following paragraph talking about a specific artwork by Sarah Lucas, titled 'Self-portrait with fried eggs' or her series of portraits called 'Self-Portrait'?

It's the [self-portrait with fried eggs](http://www.tate.org.uk/art/artworks/lucas-self-portrait-with-fried-eggs-p78447) given the article mentions the 'ancient Indian' dancing girl, and the pose she strikes.

> What is the eternal triangle here?

The pudenda - just look at both artworks!

> The ancient Indian model would have got the joke. Mean?

This is referring to a famous statuette of a [dancing girl](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Girl_(Mohenjo-daro)) discovered in a city-state of the Indus Valley - Mohenjo Daro; her attitude of 'crude defiance and flirtatious come-on'.

[This isn't the actual 'erotic sculpture' of 9th C India, mentioned by Ramachandra in the book; it's not specifically identified, being mentioned only in passing just before the passage quoted; but it's a good stand in].

The 'joke' is the joke Lucas is playing with the notion of the conventions of self-portrait; and therefore on the audience expectations or *gaze* - fried eggs being used as 'crude' symbols of sexuality; a little like how Manet played with the conventions of the nude in his painting [olympia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympia_(Manet)); again the same 'self-determination'; though there her hand covers the 'eternal triangle'.